# BIOS detect switched Drive

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, boot, ssd, asus-laptop

I just bought a new ASUS laptop with 1 SSD and 1 HDD. First, I installed Ubuntu 17.10 on SSD, but it couldn't start (with `TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to errata` message), so format everything and install Window10 on SSD instead.

Everything worked just fine so I decided to install Ubuntu 17.10 again. I googled and found a solution to `TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to errata` message, by updating BIOS from ASUS support site. (But I have not installed Ubuntu yet)

After finished the update I start my laptop again and it directed me to the BIOS setting menu, which has no drive on it (not found SSD and HDD). 
I found that I should go to `System Configuration > SATA Operation and select AHCI.` and restart. Then both SSD and HDD are found in the menu. Then I boot it with SSD (which has only Windows10 installed), but it directed me to this page:

```
error: unknown filesystem.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

So I restart and try booting with the **HDD** (**which has no OS in it**), and the **Windows 10 started** unexpectedly. In `This PC` menu in Windows 10 shows that Windows 10 is installed on SDD (which is correct).

It seemed like my laptop switch the HDD and SSD, how can I fix it?

For summary:

1. I installed Ubuntu 17.10 on SSD and couldn't open it
2. I formatted and installed Windows 10 on SSD instead
3. I updated my ASUS BIOS and change SATA Operation to AHCI
4. The HDD and SSD are switched
5. I booted with SSD (which has Windows 10) and the directed me to grub rescue
6. I booted with HDD (which has no OS) and the Windows 10 is booted

Edited: I used MBR on my HDD

Comment: Did you use MBR or GPT on the HDD?  Update the question, do not reply supply the information, in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only using windows, you do not need grub. I would boot into Linux via a USB drive and examine your SSD as well as your HDD to see if there are any residual boot partitions (i.e. grub) that were not formatted. It could be that when you boot into the blank drive the bios searches for OSes and when if finds one, goes straight to it skipping over grub (which sounds to me is still on your SSD).

Comment: Ok, so now I removed grub https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader and everything came back to normal (correct showing drive), so then I want to install Ubuntu in SSD, and on selecting drive (install along side Windows 10) it only showed the HDD and Windows 10 is also in that HDD. How do I fix this?

Comment: Likely the issue you had was because you partitioned wrong. I would look up a tutorial about the correct way to partition your drives with windows being on a separate drive. Either that or if you want an easy way, just unplug your Windows drive, Install Ubuntu normally, then plug it back in and run sudo update-grub.